# Python global variables don't seem to work across modules

Tags: python, global-variables

### Code

I'd like to use a global variable in other modules with having changes to its value "propagated" to the other modules.

a.py:

```
x="fail"
def changeX():
    global x
    x="ok"
```

b.py:

```
from a import x, changeX
changeX()
print x
```

If I run b.py, I'd want it to print "ok", but it really prints "fail".

### Questions

1. Why is that?
2. How can I make it print "ok" instead?

(Running python-2.7)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short: you can't make it print "ok" without modifying the code.

`from a import x, changeX` is equivalent to:

```
import a
x = a.x
changeX = a.changeX
```

In other words, `from a import x` doesn't create an `x` that indirects to `a.x`, it creates a new global variable `x` in the `b` module with the *current* value of `a.x`. From that it follows that later changes to `a.x` do not affect `b.x`.

To make your code work as intended, simply change the code in `b.py` to `import a`:

```
import a
a.changeX()
print a.x
```

You will have less cluttered imports, easier to read code (because it's clear what identifier comes from where without looking at the list of imports), less problems with circular imports (because not all identifiers are needed at once), and a better chance for tools like `reload` to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add another import statement after `changeX`. This would turn the code from b.py into

```
from a import x, changeX
changeX()
from a import x
print x
```

This illustrates that by calling `changeX`, only `x` in module `a` is changed. Importing it again, binds the updated value again to the identifier `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use mutable container, for example list:

a.py

```
x = ['fail']

def changeX():
    x[0] = 'ok'
```

b.py

```
from a import changeX, x

changeX()
print x[0]
```