# Change global variable across class in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to make a change to a global variable across classes. Here is my code:

file main.py

```
import class2

class first:
    def changeA(self):
        global a
        print a
        a += 2
        print a

test0 = first()
test1 = class2.second()
test2 = first()
test3 = class2.second()
test0.changeA()
test1.changeA()
test2.changeA()
test3.changeA()
```

file class2.py

```
a = 1

class second:
    def changeA(self):
        global a
        print a
        a += 1
        print a
```

But it returns an error: global name 'a' is not defined. Is there any proper way to access and change a global variable across files in python? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python global variables don't seem to work across modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403357/python-global-variables-dont-seem-to-work-across-modules)

Comment: @IanAuld: because I want to change it across some python files. I still don't find another way to do that

Comment: @ferryard If you have a variable/value that you find yourself needing across several files you most likely have a design problem. You may want to reevaluate how you have your app broken up. You may want to consider using a config file/dictionary or refactoring your code to eliminate the need for passing this value around or just importing it if it's a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Global variables don't exist in python.**

The `global` statement is really a misnomed statement. What it means is that the variable is a *module*'s variable. There is no such a thing as a global namespace in python.

If you want to modify a variable from multiple modules you *must* set it as an attribute:

```
import module

module.variable = value
```

Doing a simple assignment will simply create or modify a module's variable. The code

```
from module import variable

variable = value
```

simply shadows the value of `variable` imported from `module` creating a *new* binding with that identifier but `module`'s `variable` value will *not* be changed.

In summary: no there is no way to achieve exactly what you want (although what you want would be a bad practice anyway, and you should try to use a different solution).

Answer (score 1):

global variables are evil: avoid them!

It is much better to use a 'static' (in C++ terms) member variable, such as:

```
from class2 import second
class first:
    def changeA(self):
        print second.a
        second.a += 2
        print second.a
```

And:

```
class second:
    a = 1
    def changeA(self):
        print second.a
        second.a += 2
        print second.a
```