# Python modify global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, global-variables, global

So, this is a bit tricky.

file1.py

```
a = None

def set_a():
    global a
    a = 10
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import a, set_a

set_a()
print(a)
```

output:

```
None
```

Why a's value didn't change? I know there are other ways to change the value of a, but why this doesn't work?

Comment: `set_a` does not _call_ function `set_a`

Comment: Even if what you are trying to do works, I'd suggest finding another way of solving the issue, you will probably run into [Cyclical dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python) problems

Comment: @zvone, my bad, I changed it to set_a. It was a typo. The problem was not because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big problem is where `globals` actually lives. Each script has its own `globals`. So the `globals` that is in `set_a` really points to `file1`'s scope:

```py
import file1

file1.set_a()
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
file1.a
10
```

This change does not persist to your calling script. So let's just avoid the `global` entirely.

It would be much clearer for the function to just *return* the value, which you can name whatever you want in the calling script:

```py
# file1.py
def set_a():
    return 10
```

```py
# file2.py
from file1 import set_a

# this doesn't have any reliance on a name existing
# in any namespaces
a = set_a()
```

The general concensus on the issue is to avoid globals where possible, as they can make your code difficult to maintain.

Comment: found the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403357/python-global-variables-dont-seem-to-work-across-modules